# Convert sty-file created for prosper package for use in beamer class

Tags: beamer, presentations

Is there any way of manipulating a `.sty` file, that was originally created to be used in the prosper-class (for presentation slides) in such way, that it easily can be used as a beamer template in the `beamer` class as well?

I got the `.sty` file below and have to make it usable for the beamer-class and have literally no idea how to Approach the problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

It is about this `.sty`:

```
%==============================================================================
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01] \ProvidesPackage{PPRfolien-neues-cd}[2013/02/19]

%\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}

\ColorFoot{\black}

% The fonts
\ifDVItoPS%
\FontTitle{%
  \usefont{T1}{cmr}{b}{n}\fontsize{12pt}{20pt}\selectfont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{cmr}{b}{n}\fontsize{12pt}{20pt}\selectfont}
\FontText{%
  \usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont}

% Positionning of the title of a slide.
\newcommand{\slidetitle}[1]{%
  \rput[l](-0.15,4.1){\usefont{T1}{cmr}{b}{n}\fontsize{12pt}{13.6pt}
  \selectfont{#1}}
}
\else%
\FontTitle{%
  \usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}\fontsize{12pt}{20pt}\selectfont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}\fontsize{12pt}{20pt}\selectfont}
\FontText{%
  \usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont}

% Positionning of the title of a slide.
\newcommand{\slidetitle}[1]{%
  \rput[l](-0.15,4.1){\usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}\fontsize{12pt}{13.6pt}
  \selectfont{#1}}
}
\fi

\ifDVItoPS%
    \usepackage{exscale}
\else%
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
\fi

\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}{\hfill }{\hfill%
  \ifisDraft  % are we in draft mode?
    {\@colorFoot\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{5pt}{6pt}\selectfont
    \textbf{\jobname.tex}~--~\@Title%
     ~--~\@Author~--~\number\day/\number\month/\number\year%
     ~--~\timenow~--~S.~\thepage\ifallPages/\realpageref{last@page}\fi}
  \else
    \ifshowVersion % should we display version information?
      {\@colorFoot\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{5pt}{6pt}\selectfont
      \textbf{\jobname.tex}~--~\@Title%
       ~--~\@Author~--~\number\day/\number\month/\number\year%
       ~--~\timenow~--~S.~\thepage\ifallPages/\realpageref{last@page}\fi}
    \else
      {\@colorFoot\rput[rb](0.5,0.2){\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\fontsize{5pt}{6pt}\selectfont
      \@cartouche~~% Wenn die Seitenzahl eingefügt werden soll: \@cartouche~~\thepage
       \ifallPages/\realpageref{last@page}\fi}}
    \fi
 \fi
}

\newcommand{\BSquareFrame}[1]{%
  \psset{unit=1mm}
  \psset{linewidth=.1mm}
    \psline(80,72)(80,83.5)
    \psline(0,72)(118,72)
    \rput(100,77.7){\includegraphics*[height=9mm]{Logo}}% }
  \PutLogo % Mandatory
  {#1}
}

\myitem{1}{$\bullet$}
\myitem{2}{--}
\myitem{3}{-}

\NewSlideStyle[118mm]{t}{6,3}{BSquareFrame}
\PDFCroppingBox{10 15 594 840}

\endinput
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Some basic information how to do this is described in Beamer documentation (se chapter 24 on page 219).

Comment: Did the beamer user guide solve the issue? Otherwise maybe post an image how the theme should look like, maybe it is not too hard to reproduce it in beamer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments - maybe